# Which would take less processing power, drawing many vector images rapidly? Or drawing a bitmap repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bitmap, liquidfun

Hello I am using liquidfun.js to simulate a particle system.
I am drawing the system using an html5 canvas.
The simulation becomes laggy well below the 34k particles that the google engineers say that they get. Mines becomes a slideshow at around 4k.

Currently I draw the particles using

```
context.arc((particles[k] * mToPx) + offsetX, (particles[k+1] * mToPx) + offsetY, 9.5 , 0, 2*Math.PI );
```

for every particle in the system.

Would something like

```
context.drawImage(img,(particles[k] * mToPx) + offsetX, (particles[k+1] * mToPx));
```

be more efficient?

Is there a way to measure efficiency besides adding particles and looking for lag?

Comment: chrome profiling is a great way to test functions time use

Comment: Ah, I used it before. I'll try it again and see. Forgot about that. I stopped using chrome for this project since firefox seems to be a lot more efficient at drawing the particles than chrome.

Comment: `drawImage` is more efficient than `arc` because drawImage just copies pixel data from source to destination (it's verrry fast) while arc must actually calculate the positions of the pixels before drawing them.

Comment: I figured as much but I wanted a little confirmation before I actually tested it myself. The project is close to complete so I'm trying to avoid wasting time.

Comment: webgl would work much faster as well. And you can also try adding the other optional parameters to drawImage

Comment: I am interested in what you say about using webGL. From what I've been reading a canvas is a webGL element. What are you recommending?